# NullPointerException loading htm file from assets in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to retrieve a htm file and show it in a webview inside an Android app. This is my code:

```
private void ShowPage()
{
        location = "file:///android_asset/general.htm";
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl(location);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

}
```

I am getting a NullPointerException? Where am I going wrong? This code worked fine in Eclipse?

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.test.HomeActivity.setWebPage(HomeActivity.java:108)
            at com.test.HomeActivity.onSectionAttached(HomeActivity.java:81)
            at com.test.HomeActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onAttach(HomeActivity.java:186)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5285)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the assets folder:

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the NullPointerException? Check whether `R.id.webview` exists.

Comment: Post your Stack trace please.

Comment: I am getting the error at   webview.loadUrl(location);

Comment: It means that your location is wrong or element does not exist on that location.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the assets folder in Android Studio, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it is `"file:///android_asset/general.htm"` and not maybe `"file:///assets/general.htm"` ? By the way, I think you're also missing 's'. So it should be assets and not asset.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem - I was using a Navigation Drawer fragment and incorrectly referencing the webview. I'm not sure why the app crashed when attempting to load the url. Thanks everyone for your assistance!